# How to access appId in electron App

Tags: javascript, electron

In Electron app, how can I access `appId` which I have specified in `"build"` section of `package.json` :

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.myapp.Something"
}
```

In development I can import `package.json` and access it directly, however `"build"` section is gone from the packaged app. I want to use that id for node-notifier.

Comment: What is the need of this `appId`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var appId = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("path_to_package.json", 'utf8')).build.appId;
```

Answer (score -3):

In your application, it will be "com.myapp.Something"

So you don't need to read it directly from package.json

In node notifier just for appId type "com.myapp.Something"